# I can not get my If variable to work AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

This is my first time using this. I was just trying to create this times table game on AppleScript for fun but I can not seem to get it to work as it always says it is incorrect. Im a beginner at this so am probably doing something stupid :)

Heres the AppleScript:

```
display dialog "What times tables do you want the focus on?" default     answer "" buttons {"Done"} default button 1
set focusNum to the text returned of the result
set rn to random number from 1 to 12 as integer
set answer to text returned of (display dialog "What is" & space &     focusNum & space & "times" & space & rn default answer "")
set correctanswer to rn * focusNum
if correctanswer is equal to answer then
    display dialog "Correct"
else if correctanswer is not equal to answer then
    display dialog "You are Wrong :( The correct answer is " &     correctanswer buttons {"Continue"} default button 1
end if
end
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set rn to random number from 1 to 12 as integer
set answer to text returned of (display dialog "What is" 
    & space &     focusNum & space & "times" & space & rn default answer "") as integer
```

rn variable is an integer, but answer is a string. You need to make both variables of the same type to check if they're equal.